# Is it possible to split a unicode font such as Arial Unicode into a specific language block (Ex. Thai)?

Tags: c++, unicode, text, fonts, truetype

I am working with an user interface application, and I am attempting to implement various languages. The problem is that text display only supports 256 character fonts that are imported into a font tool. The font tool takes each character and converts it to a special bmp for the device to use as a text.

My issue is that I would like a specific language out of the Arial Unicode font. For example, I want to take all the Thai language characters from Arial Unicode and separate them into a special Thai font (with a max of 256 characters) so that I can load this into the program and convert it.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: This was a problem that was solved on mainstream operating systems around ~10+ years ago.  What the hell are you running to have to deal with this?

Comment: Well, I am working on a touch screen device called 4d labs picasso. Its a touchscreen lcd with an onboard graphics control and virtual engine with a c like language called 4dgl. It does have some drawbacks and one of them is no-unicode support which is why im wokrking with 256 character fonts.

Comment: Chinese and Japanese require a lot more than 256 characters. Arabic and Hebrew rely on difficult reading order (think about mixed right-to-left and left-to-right). Arabic letters look different depending on their position within the word. Hindi and Telugu use extremely complicated glyph substitutions and glyph compositions (painting sub-glyphs on top of each other, or slightly shifted), which require the features of the OpenType font format. These are all worked out in libraries such as Pango and D-Type. If your platform doesn't have a C compiler, Pango won't help much.

Answer (score 3):

Possible? Certainly, fonts are data with (usually) open specification. Which tool to use? I don't know. I guess that you could launch [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) (or other good font editor) and remove glyphs you don't need, or rearrange them as you wish.

Also you could decompile a TTF font with [TTX](http://www.letterror.com/code/ttx/index.html), edit it as plain-text and recompile again. This has the advantage of being easily scripted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but may not be very practical to do so.

As liori has pointed out, FontForge and TTX are two possible tools you can use.

However Arial Unicode is a monster of a font; I had TTX crashing on me when I tried to decompile 5-6MB ttf fonts so I don't think it will work on Arial Unicode.I imagine removing the unneeded glyphs using FontForge will be tedious as well.

Instead of trying to extract the glyphs from Arial Unicode I think the best way is to simply use smaller, script specific ttf fonts instead.